Some .desktop files let me pin them to the panel, some don't (using cinnamon)
I have 2 files in my usr/share/applications. I tried running both and pinning to taskbar. godot.desktop let me pin it, but osu.desktop only has the option "create shortcut", which won't pin it. Thoughts?
Edit: I have them both typed out in the same format, and the AppImage files are in the same directories.

It may help so much if you include the contents of both of the desktop files in your post. Use "edit".
